# Can I find the PID of a running process using only ls?

Tags: linux, bash, pid, ls

How can I find the PID of a running process using `ls` in bash? Let's assume I know the name of the process. Using `ps` would be easy. If I were to search for firefox, it would simply be `ps ax | grep firefox`. However for arguments sake, let's say I can't do that and I have to use `ls`.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Why do you think that `ls` is the solution here?

Comment: When I try to open a tin of beans I do not think that I may be able to use the Hoover

Comment: I know that `ls` is obviously not the solution, it's just what I have to use.

Comment: @EdHeal Terrible metaphor, a hoover might actually be able to open a tin of bins.

Comment: @broSlow - I just imagine now you, hoover and tin of beans fighting it out in the kitchen. I am going done to put my money on the beans winning :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/proc` file system has a directory entry for each process. Each directory contains a file that is a symbolic link to the executable. If you can filter the list with `grep` for example you can get the PID from the path. For example:

```
$ ls -l /proc/*/exe | grep firefox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 joni     joni     0 Feb  9 01:39 /proc/8321/exe -> /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 joni     joni     0 Feb  9 00:09 /proc/8825/exe -> /usr/lib/firefox/plugin-container
```

Comment: I hate that these questions get downvoted so much. This is actually a very educational question. I think it's extremely interesting that the kernel exposes itself via the filesystem in this way. Sometimes, deviating from the established way and "best practices" is the best way to learn/discover new things.

Comment: @ThorX89 It's an educational point that `/proc` lists process information on particular systems. But `ls` is still completely off the ball here and won't necessarily find all process names (doing something like reading `/proc/*/cmdline` would be better). And would be willing to bet the question would get less downvotes if op explained why he needed rather than just stating 'I need ls to do this'.

Comment: I would be willing to bet the reason the OP needs to use `ls` (and wouldn't say why) is because he has a homework assignment due that is attempting to teach him procfs.

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following solution:   :)

```
ls -l /proc/*/exe | grep firefox | cut -d/ -f3
```